# Most efficient way to mainupulate a object - byref or return value

Tags: c#, return-value, byref

Since in C# value types are transportet ByValue when used as parameter for a function whereas objects are transported ByRef. So my question is: What is better (faster/more performant/takes less memory)?

To give you a sample:

```
    public void ChangeObjectByRef(MyObject mo)
    {
        mo.Name = "Test2";
        mo.Values.Add("Value4");
    }

    public MyObject ChangeObjectReturnValue(MyObject mo)
    {
        mo.Name = "Test2";
        mo.Values.Add("Value4");
        return mo;
    }

    public void ChangeMyObject()
    {
        MyObject mo1 = new MyObject()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "Test",
            Values = new List<string>(){
                "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"
            }
        };

        MyObject mo2 = new MyObject()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "Test",
            Values = new List<string>(){
                "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"
            }
        };

        ChangeObjectByRef(mo1);
        mo2 = ChangeObjectReturnValue(mo2);

        Console.WriteLine(mo1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(mo2.ToString());

    }
    public class MyObject
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> Values { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("[ID={0}, Name={1}, Values={2}", ID, Name, string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", Values)));
        }
    }
```

The result is the same (obvious). But is there a difference between these two methodes?

Comment: `whereas objects are transported ByRef`  No.  *All* values are passed by value unless explicitly marked with `ref` or `out`.  The value of a reference type simply is a reference, which is what is then copied.  That's a very different semantic.

Comment: If you want to know if there's a performance difference, run the code and find out for yourself.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `mo2` to `ChangeObjectReturnValue`?  Otherwise you're just assigning an updated version of `mo1` to `mo2` and losing the second `MyObject` that you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually working with value types, see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) for details of value types. What you are actually passing is a pointer to that object rather than the object itself. So extending on what @juharr has put in the comments you will lose mo2 as you are overriding it with the pointer of your first object. See code example of what would actually happen

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Demo demo = new Demo { A = "ABC" };
            Demo demo2;
            OptionOne(demo);
            Console.WriteLine(demo.A); //Outputs World
            demo2 = OptionTwo(demo);
            Console.WriteLine(demo.A); //Outputs Hello
            Console.WriteLine(demo2.A); //Output Hello
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void OptionOne(Demo demo)
        {
            demo.A = "World";
        }
        private static Demo OptionTwo(Demo demo)
        {
            demo.A = "Hello";
            return demo;
        }
    }
    public class Demo
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
    }
```